# spring3 setIgnoreUnknownFields

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a hidden field "tmpFileId" in the form which I don't want to bind to the model. I want to get it using http servlet request's getParameter request. So I did this in my controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setIgnoreUnknownFields(false);
}
```

But whether I set it `true` or `false` as the parameter for `setIgnoreUnknownFields` I am getting the error

```
"Invalid property 'tmpFileId' of bean class [tms.TrainingInstructor]: Bean property 'tmpFileId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"
```

From the documentation:

```
public void setIgnoreUnknownFields(boolean ignoreUnknownFields)

    Set whether to ignore unknown fields, that is, whether to ignore bind parameters that do not have corresponding fields in the target object.

    Default is "true". Turn this off to enforce that all bind parameters must have a matching field in the target object.

    Note that this setting only applies to binding operations on this DataBinder, not to retrieving values via its BindingResult.

    See Also:
        bind(org.springframework.beans.PropertyValues)
```

So now I am not sure whether I am doing things all right. From the text "Note that this setting only applies to binding operations on this DataBinder, not to retrieving values via its BindingResult", does it mean that it will work only for binding while get (ie the rendering jsp from model) and not post (ie from jsp to model)?

Thanks

PS: my jsp

```
<form:form method="post" action="addEditTrainingInstructor" commandName="trainingInstructor">
    <form:hidden path="id" />
    <form:hidden path="tmpFileId" />
</form:form>
```

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addEditTrainingInstructor", params="create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEditTrainingInstructor(@ModelAttribute("trainingInstructor")TrainingInstructor instructor, BindingResult result, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Integer classID = (Integer) session.getAttribute("TrainingClassID");
    TrainingClass trainingClass = new TrainingClass();
    trainingClass.setId(classID);

    String tmpFileId = request.getParameter("tmpFileId");

    logger.debug("class ID for instructor: "+classID);
    instructor.setTrainingClass(trainingClass);
    tmsService.saveTrainingInstructor(instructor);              
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TrainingInstructor")
public class TrainingInstructor {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name="TrainingClassID", referencedColumnName="id")
    private TrainingClass trainingClass;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name="StuffID", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Stuff instructor;

    @Column(name="certificatecopy")
    private byte[] certificate;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Stuff getInstructor() {
        return instructor;
    }

    public void setInstructor(Stuff instructor) {
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }

    public byte[] getCertificate() {
        return certificate;
    }

    public void setCertificate(byte[] certificate) {
        this.certificate = certificate;
    }

    public TrainingClass getTrainingClass() {
        return trainingClass;
    }

    public void setTrainingClass(TrainingClass trainingClass) {
        this.trainingClass = trainingClass;
    }


}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'tmpFileId' of bean class [tms.TrainingInstructor]: Bean property 'tmpFileId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'tmpFileId' of bean class [tms.TrainingInstructor]: Bean property 'tmpFileId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:723)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:714)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag.writeTagContent(HiddenInputTag.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.trainingInstructorForm_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fhidden_005f1(trainingInstructorForm_jsp.java:223)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.trainingInstructorForm_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(trainingInstructorForm_jsp.java:141)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.trainingInstructorForm_jsp._jspService(trainingInstructorForm_jsp.java:98)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: please post your form code. I think your problem could be here

Comment: The default which is true(to ignore unknown fields) should have worked for you!, tested with Spring 4.0.1 and it appears to work cleanly.

Comment: Can you please post the code for the `tms.TrainingInstructor` class ?